# Generate JSON XML string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set user info in document it say this. I will set all user info in a JSON string and give that string to soap action

```
 'Tourist'=>{"1":{"Surname":"TestG","Name":"Tesre","Sex":"man","Birthday":"19701106",
"PassportS":"TT","PassportN":"34342342","Viza":"0","DateTake":"20031113",
"DateIssue":"20281116","WhoTake":"Testes"}}',
```

Then I try to set this to string link this in c#

```
 string tourist= "Tourist'=>{"'1'":{"'Surname'":"'TestG'","'Name'":"'Tesre'","'Sex'":"'man'","'Birthday'":"'19701106'","'PassportS'":"'TT'","'PassportN'":"'34342342'","'Viza'":"'0'","'DateTake'":"'20031113'","'DateIssue'":"'20281116'","'WhoTake'":"'Testes'"}}";
```

but I get this error:

> CS1012 C# AND ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Too many characters in character literal error

Comment: Where are you closing the single quote before the `=>`?

Comment: string tourist= "Tourist'=>{"'1'":{"'Surname'":"'TestG'","'Name'":"'Tesre'","'Sex'":"'man'","'Birthday'":"'19701106'","'PassportS'":"'TT'","'PassportN'":"'34342342'","'Viza'":"'0'","'DateTake'":"'20031113'","'DateIssue'":"'20281116'","'WhoTake'":"'Testes'"}}"';

Comment: is this true?Do you mean this?

Comment: I don't understand why `'` and `"` are mixed like that.  This JSON is very broken.  None of the `"` are escaped, either.

Comment: I would *start* by avoiding creating the string yourself. If you want to create JSON, use something like Json.NET to do so. It'll be *much* easier to get that right.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would be better off using some form of JSON serialiser to do the heavy lifting. I am using Newtonsoft.JSON, but I'm sure you can use any serialiser.

Basically they take a C# class and create a JSON string from the public attributes (the public items with "get" on them).

In terms of your problem, precisely, the string you are creating is malformed:

```
string tourist= **"Tourist'=>{"**'1'":{"'Surname'":"'TestG'","'Name'":"'Tesre'","'Sex'":"'man'","'Birthday'":"'19701106'","'PassportS'":"'TT'","'PassportN'":"'34342342'","'Viza'":"'0'","'DateTake'":"'20031113'","'DateIssue'":"'20281116'","'WhoTake'":"'Testes'"}}";
```

The first part, "Tourist'=>{", is a string which has opening and closing quotes. Everything else is just confusing for the compiler. You either need to use a "verbatim string literal", where the quotes are escaped by doubling them:

```
string tourist = @"Tourist'=>{""'1'"":{""'Surname'"":""'TestG'"",""'Name'"":""'Tesre'"",""'Sex'"":""'man'"",""'Birthday'"":""'19701106'"",""'PassportS'"":""'TT'"",""'PassportN'"":""'34342342'"",""'Viza'"":""'0'"",""'DateTake'"":""'20031113'"",""'DateIssue'"":""'20281116'"",""'WhoTake'"":""'Testes'""}}";
```

Or you can use a normal string, and escape the quotes with a slash:

```
string tourist = "Tourist'=>{\"'1'\":{\"'Surname'\":\"'TestG'\",\"'Name'\":\"'Tesre'\",\"'Sex'\":\"'man'\",\"'Birthday'\":\"'19701106'\",\"'PassportS'\":\"'TT'\",\"'PassportN'\":\"'34342342'\",\"'Viza'\":\"'0'\",\"'DateTake'\":\"'20031113'\",\"'DateIssue'\":\"'20281116'\",\"'WhoTake'\":\"'Testes'\"}}";
```

However, I'm not sure why you are quoting your quoted strings, anyway. You should be able to remove the internal double quotes, and just use the single quotes:

```
string tourist = @"Tourist'=>{'1':{'Surname':'TestG','Name':'Tesre','Sex':'man','Birthday':'19701106','PassportS':'TT','PassportN':'34342342','Viza':'0','DateTake':'20031113','DateIssue':'20281116','WhoTake':'Testes'}}";
```

(you might want to look at the opening "Tourist'=>".  The single-quote looks wrong here.)